# How to fill empty cells in Col B based on relationship between filled cells in Col A and Col B

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

*Existing data set:*

```
CA   |  CB

AA   |  1

AA   | 

BB   |

BB   |  2

CC   |  1

CC   |
```

*Required data set – fill empty cells in column CB with related value as established between column CA and column CB (if value AA in column CA has corresponding value of 1 in column CB, then all instances of AA in column CA should have related value of 1 in column CB):*

```
CA   | CB

AA   |  1

AA   |  1

BB   |  2

BB   |  2

CC   |  1

CC   |  1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a VLOOKUP.

To create the table, write out all the CA values vs their CB counterparts. If this is too long to write by hand, take the list you currently have, sort it by CA and then CB (reversed) so that the top value of each set of CA is not blank, and then use Excel's Remove Duplicates on both columns but only using the variable CA. It should look like this

```
CA | CB

AA | 1

BB | 2

CC | 1
```

Then use a VLOOKUP formula to read the CB value from the list.